# How would I implement single sign on, over the internet, using both OAuth and Active Directory

Tags: java, oauth, active-directory, single-sign-on

OAuth is obviously a godsend when it comes to doing single-sign on, although there are doubtless headaches involved in merging different applications' user databases, but we also have a customer requirement to support Active Directory. Can anyone suggest any suitable architectures (or indeed resources/information on the web) for having multiple websites achieve single sign on, using both OAuth and Active Directory? It's conceivable that one domain could be set to be either one or the other, but the ideal would be that we cope with both (e.g. attempt AD auth and fallback to OAuth if not, perhaps?).

We're a primarily Java-based development house, with rich-client web front-ends. We do use EC2 for some of our apps, but also host on our own servers. Ideally any solution would not care about the location of the application itself.

All suggestions and opinions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider some form of identity federation using SAML-P or WS-Federation.

ADFS in Server 2012 R2 comes with OAuth2 support.  Or you could look into [AuthorizationServer](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/09/19/adding-oauth2-to-adfs-and-thus-bridging-the-gap-between-modern-applications-and-enterprise-back-ends/).

But it might be worth reading [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/02/oauth-2-0-and-sign-in-4/), first.  Good luck!

Comment: In the absence of any other information, this is definitely useful enough to answer my question and put me on the right track. Thank you.